# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn' Getting this error

Tags: dataframe, object, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, attributes

I am trying to do string Matching. But when I am getting this error while creating a column. Please help. (AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn')

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame

def matchstring(s1, s2):
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1, s2)

MatchUDF = f.udf(matchstring, StringType())

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()


df_merged = ps.merge(df_Sale_KR,df_Dist_Mast, on='Distributor_ID', how='left')

df_similarity_score = df_merged.withColumn("similarity_score", MatchUDF(f.col("source"), f.col("target")))
df_similarity_score.show()
```

Comment: Where is `ps` coming from?

Comment: I have imported Pandas as  'ps'

Comment: I can't currently test this so may be a bit off, but pandas merge-function doesn't return a pyspark dataframe, it returns a pandas dataframe which - as far as I know - does not implement withColumn. Try converting the pandas dataframe to a pyspark one before calling that function on it.

Comment: I tried that, but getting this error:

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: